# Hibernate: How can I join 2 classes in one table?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa

So, I'm pretty new to Hibernate and I have a problem.

I have an abstract class (the super-class, class Super), and 5 subclasses which should use the proprieties from the class Super and add a new propriety (a new column)

So how can I do this? Should I extend the class Super from java, or it's enough to join the classes using a JPA annotation.

Here is the second problem. How can I have 1 table for 2 classes. 
Someone (smarter than me) told me to use the  **@JoinTable**, but form my searches with google, I think I need to use **@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceStrategy.JOINED)**

Can I use the **@JoinTable** too?

Answer (score 5):

Yours is a case of inheritance:

1. add the `@Inheritance(stretegy=InheritanceStrategy.SINGLE_TABLE)` annotation on your `Super`
2. add the `@DiscriminatorColumn` annotation (and setting its attributes `name` and `discriminatorType`) (again on the `Super`)
3. on each subclass `extend` the `Super`, and add the annotation `@DiscriminatorValue`, with different value for each of the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Hibernate, you should read its [documentation.](https://www.hibernate.org/5.html) Inheritance strategies are explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html) and using annotations to express inheritance strategy is explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e829)